# How to get two buttons on same row in a table

Tags: php, html

I have a problem to get two buttons on same row in table. I have searched solution for hours and hours but no luck. Here is my current code.

```html
    <form class="controlbox" name="Register" id="registration" action="index.php" method="POST">
    <table style="margin-right: auto;">
    <tr>
      <td style="border: 1px solid gray;"><a href=”index.php”><button>Back</button></a></td>
      <td style="border: 1px solid gray;"><input type="submit" value="Register" onclick="User.processRegistration()"/></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

I don't know how to make those buttons to show on same row inside separate td's.

Comment: You put them in separate td's? I don't see the problem here.

Comment: @aynber Oh sorry, my mistake. I moved last one into first td while I was doing my question, I forgot about it because something else got my attention for a while. I now tried it back in second td and still no change. Second button is showing above the second td. That was my original problem and still is.

Comment: @aynber I edited the code now to mach my question.

Comment: It seems to work fine. I changed your post to be a snippet so it can generate the table, and it works just fine.

Comment: It does not work on my machine. Check this screenshot. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c3r2gtmOFQAlw5nLFCDOfgE_K-g27pEg/view?usp=sharing Register button is above the second td

Comment: It looks like there's a box under your register button, maybe an input box? Is this your full code, or did you remove something from it, such as an input or image?

Comment: No there is not. This code here is exactly as the code that shows that screenshot. Button in other td and submit button input in second td. This just what makes me baffled why submit button is outside of that td. I changed second td like this : <td style="border: 1px solid gray;"><button onclick="User.processRegistration()">Register</button></td> now button is inside the td but it does not fire User.processRegistration() function. How to fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. Here is my code for my future reference and to others who are seeking this same information.

```
<form class="controlbox" name="Register" id="registration" action="index.php" method="POST">
  <table style="margin-right: auto;">
    <tr>
      <td style="border: 1px solid gray;"><a href=”index.php”><button>Back</button></a></td>
      <td style="border: 1px solid gray;"><button type="submit" onclick="User.processRegistration()">Register</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Thank you anyway @aynber for your efforts